# bgStretcher plugin - multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Using the jQuery plugin bgStretcher 2 ([link to plugin](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html)), I am attempting to have various `<div>`s on one page use its functionality. However the plugin only appears to support one instance per page, if I make more than one `$("#element").bgStretcher()` call then only the first one works and all others are ignored and "More than one bgStretcher" is logged in the console.

Are there any ways around this, or are there any other plugins which would do something similar, i.e. intelligently stretch an image to fill an element? I've attempted to hack out the relevant parts of this plugin to do this but with no luck.

Using background-size: 100% doesn't work as this won't fill the element space vertically, it just stretches horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

If your design allows you to display only one bgstretcher instance at a time, you can destroy the active one and create another one.

```
$('#slide1').bgStretcher.sliderDestroy();

$('#slide2').bgStretcher({
    images: imagesArray,
    imageWidth: 1600,
    imageHeight: 800,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a containerID?

```
el1.bgStretcher({
                containerId: "bgstretcher1",
                images : [...],
                ... further settings ...
})
el1.bgStretcher({
                containerId: "bgstretcher2",
                images : [...],
                ... further settings ...
})
```